# Ruby Rails: wont save as decimal in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Im using Ruby 2.4.1 with rails 5.0.2

Here is my code:

```
total_price = 600.0
o = client.bills.new(client_id: client, total_price: total_price.to_f)
#<Bill id: nil, client_id: 21, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, total_price: 0.6e3, bill_id: nil, discount_price: nil>
o.save
```

it will save as `0.00` instead of `600.0` or `0.6e3` in my PostgreSQL. Oh, im using Numeric(8,2) as its datatypes which is `decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2`

My migration:

```
add_column :bills, :total_price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

Any clues?

Comment: `total_price: 0.6e3` is not zero.

Comment: yes true.. but when is save, it save as 0.00

Comment: could you please add your migration and schema/structure file?

Comment: show me the output of `o.update_column(total_price: 123.45)`. If that works it means you have some validation or something else preventing the correct number to be saved

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it return 0.12345e3 but still save it as 0.00

Comment: @marmeladze here it is `add_column :bills, :total_price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2`

Comment: nvm, found the problem, you are right @AndreyDeineko i have callback after_function

Comment: But it's strange, because `update_column` should have bypassed any callbacks. Anyway, I can post that as an answer to get some free rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some validation/callback preventing the correct value to be written to database. Double check validations/callbacks in `Bill` model.

Comment: you are right.. i forgot that i have callback after_create.. thanks for your hint!